# Dependency Injection failure using the ABP Framework

Tags: c#, abp

I am attempting to perform Dependency Injection (DI), but everything appears to be failing. Essentially, I have a YAML file that I want to parse once the application starts. To achieve this, I have created several classes, such as:

```
public class LessonParametersService : ISingletonDependency, ILessonParametersService
{
    private OpenAIManager _openAiManager;

    public LessonParametersService(OpenAIManager openAiManager)
    {
        _openAiManager = openAiManager;
    }

    public async Task<string> getResult()
    {
        var result = await _openAiManager.GetCompletion("you are a useful assitant");
        return result;

    }

}

public class OpenAIManager : ISingletonDependency
```

I am aware that there are multiple methods to accomplish this, but none of them appear to be effective for me at the moment. I am struggling with making the getResult method run correctly and resolving the associated error. I am unsure of what exactly is causing the issue and why I am receiving this exception.

Furthermore, I attempted to register manually using the following code:

```
  context.Services.AddSingleton<OpenAIManager>();
        context.Services.AddSingleton<LessonParametersService>(
            sp => sp.GetRequiredService<LessonParametersService>()
        );
```

I am currently feeling a bit lost and would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: ABP doesn't provide its own DI infrastructure. It uses .NET Core's DI. No special interfaces are needed. Assuming you use .NET 6 or 7 you can register both services with `builder.Services.AddSingleton<OpenAIManager>(); builder.Services.AddSingleton<LessonParametersService>();`. When you try to  create a `LessonParametersService` instances through either `IServiceProvider` directly or indirectly (eg as a controller dependency) the DI middleware will create the `OpenAIManager` as well

Answer (score 0):

The assembly containing these classes must have an abp module. If you are using autofac, you should implement autofac.

Autofac implemention:
Module class:

```cs
[DependsOn(typeof(AbpAutofacModule))]
public class MyModule : AbpModule
{
   //...
}
```

Program.cs:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    internal static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .UseAutofac(); //Integrate Autofac!
}
```

or

```cs
public class Program
{
    public async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Host.UseAutofac(); // Integrate Autofac!
        await builder.AddApplicationAsync<MyProjectNameWebModule>();
        var app = builder.Build();
        await app.InitializeApplicationAsync();
        await app.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Resources:
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Dependency-Injection
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Autofac-Integration#install-autofac-integration